# Let $T$ be a mobius transformation such that $T(3i)=5$ and $T$ maps circle $\{|z-i|=4\}$ onto circle $\{|z-2|=2\}.$ Determine all values of $T(9i) $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T$ be a mobius transformation such that $T(3i)=5$ and $T$ maps circle $\{|z-i|=4\}$ onto circle $\{|z-2|=2\}.$ Could anyone advise me how to find all possible values of $T(9i)  \ ?$

A mobius transformation is a composite of translation, rotation + dilation and reciprocation. There seem to be too many ways to compose this transformation. How do I make use of $T(3i)=5 ?$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the points $3i$ and $9i$ are conjugate with respect to the circle $|z-i|=4$ (they are on the same ray from $i$, and the product of their distances from $i$ is equal to $4^2$). Mobius transformations always send conjugate points to conjugate points, implying $T(9i)$ has one possible value, the conjugate of $5$ in the circle $|z-2|=2$.

Comment: Thanks for reply. To prove $3i$ and $9i$ are conjugate with respect to circle $|z-i|=4,$ one needs to show $\dfrac{(3i-a)(9i-a)}{(3i-b)(9i-b)}=-1,$ for any circle that passing through $9i,3i$ and cutting $|z-i|=4$ at $a,b \ ?$